# Xcode 9 fail to add target membership

Tags: ios, xcode

After update to latest XCode 9 i mention that after i drag files to project and checkmark (add files to target ) is on, still, files is added without checked target membership.

It is really frustrating, sometimes you may need to add whole library to project, and i finished up checking each file and put checkmark to target membership.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I had same issue. are you using beta version of Xcode 9?

Comment: @HashemAboonajmi i use Version 9.0 (9A235)

Comment: You can select all files at once and then check mark them for the target as an alternative

Comment: I always add files to project folder first and then use Add Files To <project>.. to add them in XCode

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban please update to Xcode 9.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experienced similar issue with Xcode 9.0.1 and it appears that somewhy checkbox `create folder references` was checked instead of `create groups`. So I chose `create groups` and it worked.
[image]

Comment: This worked for me